# Table column alignment: Align all numbers (some of which are in an fbox) to the right

Tags: tables, boxes, arrays

I probably have a very simple question. I'm trying to format a table of numbers with all columns aligned to the right. The table contains numbers and I want some of the numbers to be in a "frame" (e.g. like this: \fbox{42}). See the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{r|}}
            \fbox{0}    &   0       &   0       &   0   \\
            \fbox{11}   &   11      &   11      &   11  \\
                2       &\fbox{2}   &   2       &   2   \\
                3       &   3       &\fbox{3}   &   3   \\
                44      &\fbox{44}  &   44      &   44  \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The problem with this code is that the numbers in fboxes are shifted a bit to the left, which I don't want. I would like the numbers to be aligned to the right, but I think it's actually the fboxes which are aligned to the right.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some `\ooalign` magic.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand*\phantomfbox[1]{{%
  \ooalign{#1\cr\hidewidth\fbox{\phantom{#1}}\hidewidth\cr}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{r|}}
            \phantomfbox{0}  & 0                & 0               & 0  \\
            \phantomfbox{11} & 11               & 11              & 11 \\
                2            & \phantomfbox{2}  & 2               & 2  \\
                3            & 3                & \phantomfbox{3} & 3  \\
                44           & \phantomfbox{44} & 44              & 44 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]